# How I can get response from express with Angular 6

Tags: angular, express, mean

I have MEAN Stack app.Angular app built in public folder,so that server can run both apps on same port. Here is my back-end routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../configs/config');
const Admin = require('../models/Admin');
const _ = require('lodash');



  router.get("/login",(req,res)=>{
        console.log("loginAccess");
        res.json({
            loginaccess:true,
        });

    });


router.post('/auth',(req,res,next)=>{
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    Admin.getAdminByEmail(email, (err, admin) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!admin) {
            return res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Admin not found' });
        }

        Admin.comparePassword(password, admin.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                let payload = {
                    id: admin._id,
                    email: admin.email,
                    role:config.ADMIN_HERO_STRING
                };
                const token = jwt.sign({ payload }, config.JWT_SECRET,{
                    expiresIn:3600
                });
                Admin.updateToken(email, token, (error, success) => {
                    if (error) return console.log("Error with updating token");
                    console.log(success);
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: "jwt " + token,
                        admin: {
                            id: admin._id,
                            email: admin.email
                        }
                    });
                    // res.redirect("/admins/home");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

router.get('/manageApp',passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),(req,res)=>{
    res.json({email:req.user});
});


module.exports = router;
```

I'm looking for way which can help me to take that response from login route and use it in may angular app.For this case when I type localhost:3000/admin/login it brings the response to page like json,so my problem is to take that jso to my angular.And here is my angular admin service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {
  adminAccess:boolean=false;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router:Router) {
      this.isRealAdmin();
   }

  isRealAdmin(){
    if(this.adminAccess){
      return this.router.navigate[('login')];
    }else{
      return false
    }
  }

}
```

So as you can see its empty, because I've no idea how I can take json from express. 
 I have created component for admin login page,and if I'll take that **loginaccess** to my admin service I'll redirect to my admin login page.
 Thanks for attention and for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
this.http.get('/login').subscribe(data => console.log(data.loginaccess));
```

Express routes configuration:

```
// for web api
app.use('/api', routesApi);

// catch 404 and forward to Angular
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

// unauthorized error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401);
    res.json({
      'message': err.name + ': ' + err.message
    });
  } else {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
  }
});
```

Comment: When angular built in express app (in public folder) both applications run on same port (in this case on 3000),so when I type localhost:3000/admin/login it send request to server,then it bringing back that json from server, I just need to take that value.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you show your App Route? I would like to see how your configure the routes in Angular? I guess '/admin/login' is a Angular route, right? Thus, you will need to configure routes in express to redirect them to Angular. I attached an previous example from my project.

Comment: You was right, my mistake was setting admin service in wrong provider.